# TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined at Function.use (../index.js:464:13)

Tags: javascript, express

What is the middleware I need to get this crud app to work?
here is index.js in the backend.

### This is index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const {productRoutes} = require("../routes.js");
const cors = require("cors");
 
const app = express();
 
try {
    console.log('Database connected...');
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Connection error:', error);
}
 
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/products', productRoutes);
 
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server running at port 3000'));
```

Error message:

TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined
at Function.use (/Users/rianc/Desktop/crudexpress/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:464:13)
at Function. (/Users/rianc/Desktop/crudexpress/backend/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:220:21)
at Array.forEach ()
at Function.use (/Users/rianc/Desktop/crudexpress/backend/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:217:7)
at Object. (/Users/rianc/Desktop/crudexpress/backend/models/index.js:15:5)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)

### this is backend controller/Products.js

```
const {Products} = require("../models");
 
exports.getAllProducts = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const products = await Products.findAll();
        res.json(products);
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({ message: error.message });
    }  
}
 
exports.getProductById = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const product = await Products.findAll({
            where: {
                id: req.params.id
            }
        });
        res.json(product[0]);
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({ message: error.message });
    }  
}
 
exports.createProduct = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await Products.create(req.body);
        res.json({
            "message": "Product Created"
        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({ message: error.message });
    }  
}
 
exports.updateProduct = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await Products.update(req.body, {
            where: {
                id: req.params.id
            }
        });
        res.json({
            "message": "Product Updated"
        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({ message: error.message });
    }  
}
 
exports.deleteProduct = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await Products.destroy({
            where: {
                id: req.params.id
            }
        });
        res.json({
            "message": "Product Deleted"
        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({ message: error.message });
    }  
}
```

### This is all in the backend of the app, the front end is react.
this Routes.js

```
const express = require("express");
 
const { 
    getAllProducts,
    createProduct,
    getProductById,
    updateProduct,
    deleteProduct
} = require("../controllers/Products.js");
 
const router = express.Router();
 
router.get('/', getAllProducts);
router.get('/:id', getProductById);
router.post('/', createProduct);
router.patch('/:id', updateProduct);
router.delete('/:id', deleteProduct);
 
exports.productRoutes = router;
```

Comment: Everything looks ok. Which is line 15 of `backend/models/index.js`?

Comment: Thanks, Phil for helping.

Comment: It's saying that `productRoutes` from `routes.js` is undefined. What is in `routes.js`?

Comment: const router = express.Router()

Comment: The first step in debugging an error like this (which is something you should do before you post here) is to go to the line of code right before the error and then add a `console.log()` to see what the offending variable contains.  So, in this case go right before this line `app.use('/products', productRoutes);` and insert `console.log(typeof productRoutes, productRoutes)` and see what you have.  The error is apparently telling you that this isn't a function that it is supposed to be.  Probably this is an error in exporting and importing.  If the function is `null`, then a circular reference.

Comment: Could you please clean up your question. You've got duplicate code snippets and it's not clear which file they belong to. Please label each code snippet with the full file path from your project root, eg _"This is `backend/models/index.js`"_, _"This is `backend/routes.js`"_, etc

Comment: Why are your file paths all different format? Please just provide actual paths, aka `backend/routes.js`, **NOT** _"backend Routes.js"_. Why is `backend index.js` duplicated in `backend/models/index.js`?

Comment: I'm obviously not being clear here. Your project is in `/Users/rianc/Desktop/crudexpress`, correct? Please label each file's code snippet with the **literal file path** from that project directory. I expect to see at least `backend/models/index.js` since that's referenced in your error message. Please include the **FULL PATHS** for any other file used in your project such as `routes.js` and `controllers/Products.js`